# Reformat Time Format to non military time

Tags: php, string, datetime

I have the following string...

"20:30pm - 23:30pm"

I am trying to change the time format using strtotime, but as there is no date, it is returning FALSE.

```
$oldtime = "20:30pm - 23:30pm";
$newtime = explode(" - ", $oldtime);
foreach($newtime as $k => $t) {
  $time[$k] = strtotime($t);
}
```

But my $time array comes out as...

```
array(
  0 => FALSE,
  1 => FALSE
)
```

Is there anyway to change this into a date/time object and reformat without a day/month/year?

The ideal result is "8:30pm - 11:30pm"

Comment: `20:30pm` is not a valid time, the `pm` is superfluous.

Comment: Its all ive got to work with unfortunately, hence trying to fix it

Comment: I understand, just saying. You might want to try removing the pm as well. Is the input always in this format? Meaning two times, separated by some value?

Comment: Got ya, just removed it with str_replace and ive got a date object. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
print_r(DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i+", "20:30pm"));
```

---

The `+` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)) is used to ignore the trailing data, which in this case are the `pm` characters.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below:

```
$oldtime = "20:30pm - 23:30pm";
$newtime = explode(" - ", $oldtime);
foreach($newtime as $k => $t) {
$time[$k] = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:iA', $t);
echo $time[$k]->format('H:i:s');  //or any other format you want
}
```

You can get more info : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

if  `$oldtime = "20:30 - 23:30";`

then you can try this

```
$oldtime = "20:30 - 23:30";
$newtime = explode(" - ", $oldtime);
foreach($newtime as $k => $t) {
  $time[$k] = date("g:i a", strtotime($t));
}

print_r($time);
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like below. how-ever datetime convertion will display the executing day

```
public function test2(){
    $oldtime = str_replace("pm","","20:30pm - 23:30pm");
    $newtime = explode(" - ", $oldtime);

    foreach($newtime as $k => $t) {
        $time[$k] = strtotime($t);
    }
    print_r($time);
    echo $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A T",$time[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

This answer takes a cue from @KrisRoofe who recommends instantiating a DateTime object on the basis of a string value and its time format. He also suggests how to eliminate the need for using str_replace() by including "+" in the time format string - nice! So, that's the basis of this answer but it also has some noteworthy differences, too, as follows:

```
<?php

$oldtime = "20:30pm - 23:30pm";
$newtime = explode("-", $oldtime );

$arrStr = [];
$arrObj = [];

foreach($newtime as $elem) {

  $o = DateTime::CreateFromformat( 'H:i+',trim($elem) );
  $arrObj[] = $o;
  $arrStr[] = $o->format('g:iA');
}

echo join(" - ",$arrStr);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/WIoE8)

Upon exploding on the string containing the times in military format, the resulting array is stored in $newtime.  The foreach iterates the array using each element's value.

A static call occurs in the loop, using the CreateFromformat method of the DateTime class which yields a DateTime object which gets stored in $o. Object $o then gets assigned to an array.   Hence, the code has an array of DateTime objects with the original string values.

Next in the foreach, $o uses its format() method to reformat the value of its date property so that a new string results containing the time in a 12-hr format.  That result gets stored in an array strings which are ultimately joined to produce the ideal result per the OP's request.